# xcode not incorporating changes to root.plist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, inappsettingskit

i'm using inappsettingskit and i have everything working except that it seems to have stopped recognizing changes to my root.plist. i know i've see things before about cleaning out certain directories of xcode but the wierd thing here is that i am changing just the version of the plist file (the last key) and that does show up on my settings page, but all of the changes in the upper part of the plist file are ignored. (my version info is coming from root.plist not info.plist)

any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app from the phone/simulator and do a clean build.